# JSP multi browser compatibility

Tags: html, jsp

Any ideas to make JSP and HTML codes comply with all browsers? I tried to add the following lines on top of the .jsp page but apparenty, it didn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE ...` is not a magical keyword that will fix all incompatibilities for you. It only says the browser "Trust me. I know what I'm doing."

Comment: An answer to this question (how to make any page cross-browser compatible) would be very long. Care to post the specific page that you want to fix?

Comment: @JanDvorak: My page contain jsp (including jstl) and html codes only. So, any ideas to fix it would be appreciated. I'm willing to learn ...

Comment: Only the rendered HTML/CSS will have to be compatible, JSP/JSTL is only server-side.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: You mean it's not possible to do that?

Comment: I mean that the JSP behind has nothing to do with browser compatibility. You must check the rendered HTML instead.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: Could you please show me how to do that? Code snippet will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. load tour page in a browser 2. show source

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: Ok, after i show the source what should i do next?

Comment: Generally when I want to fix something, I start by explaining the exact problem, when my car is broken, I don't just go see at the garage and give my keys...

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: Frankly, I still can't figure out which part of my codes that should be customized in order to comply with cross-browsers. If you think I should give you the whole codes, then I might need to PM you. CMIIW